# Defining the 'Not responding' behavior of a program

Tags: android, linux, windows

I need to write an Application which continuously monitors the system's/application's behavior and  mark out the processes which are 'not responding' at all.

I mean something like this on Windows :

[image]

or like this on Android :

[image]

Can someone help me in defining out this 'hanging' or 'not responding' behaviors so that I can write an application to monitor these parameters.

I could think of just one parameter :

Constantly monitoring the processor usages of each Application, and mark them as not responding if they are consuming above 'x'% CPU for some 'y'units of time.

Platform : Linux/Android/Windows

Comment: Each OS has its own rules. In the case of Windows, it detects that an app is not pumping its message queue.

Comment: Can 'you' please explain the reason for a down vote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like a *watchdog*. Either the application has to do some pre-defined activity regularly and you just regularly check if it did this activity. Or you send some kind of request to the application which it has to answer.

*Consuming above 'x'% CPU for some 'y' units of time* has nothing to do with *not responding*. An application can consume lots of CPU but still respond to system or user events. Likewise an application can consume no CPU at all because it waits for an input, and does not respond to any other request during that time.

Comment: Your approach will require that there is some kind of understanding between my monitoring App and rest of the Apps. But my constraint is that I cant have all the Apps from known sources, they might be completely unaware of my Application as such.

Comment: Then you won't be able to tell the difference between a responding and a not responding application. It will be just a black box for you, even if it does some processing you cannot know if it got stuck in some kind of loop. Either it has to respond *to* some events *from* the outside or it has to do something *with* the outside.

Comment: Then how come Windows/Android as an OS find out which Applications are responding and which are not ? As far as I have seen we don't design the Apps to be aware of this fact, or do we ?

Comment: This is usually done automatically by some OS API/library used by all these applications which then will handle and respond to events in a regularly executed event loop. This is very OS-specific.

Answer (score 1):

We have some active processes at enterprise, and sometimes due to long time running or memory problems they close without raising exceptions. They  just die.

We have implemented a class inside this applications who is logging own process activity into files or database tables.

We use another watcher monitor who is fetching this logged data event X minutes , so if more than X minutes have passed and no logged data appears the process is not working correctly.

The we use psexec to remote kill the process and start it again.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. But your approach will work for the 'trusted' Apps only. My requirement is that I should be able to monitor and handle the 'Untrusted' Apps, as in the Apps which might not have implemented the logger class which you are providing.